# Show nothing if no data is found

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this Query that shows MAC address for a node but if no MAC address is found then it shows the entire Query instead. Is there a way to show nothing or a text that says "No MAC address" if there is no data found?

```
${SQL:SELECT TOP 1 MAC FROM NodeMACAddresses where NodeID=$@nodeid@}
```

Comment: . . If your code runs, then it is not MySQL and is most likely SQL Server.  I changed the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One pretty simply method is to use aggregation and `coalesce()`:

```
select coalesce(max(MAC), 'No Mac Address')
from NodeMACAddresses 
where NodeID = $@nodeid@;
```

An aggregation query with no `group by` always returns exactly one row.  If there are no matching rows, the values are `NULL`.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to make it check data in this order?
MAC address from NodeMACAddresses, 
Custom table: ${MAC_Address}, 
Text: No Mac Address

Comment: @Spifa . . . Probably, but if you want to introduce another table, you should ask a *new* question with sample data and desired results.